# Mongoose Stream API: Document Structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, stream, jsonstream

I'm thinking about streaming my results to a browser (using nodejs and a client library, maybe something like Oboe.js) but I have a nested document structure which is possibly indefinitely deep.

Do I have to change my document structure so my nested objects are available as separate mongo documents or is stream() also committing partial objects to the client?

Thanks :)